# What is the Mathematica equivalent for corr2?

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, matlab

What is the *Mathematica* equivalent for MATLAB's [`corr2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html), which gives the correlation coefficient of two 2D matrices?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Matlab, but see if `Correlation[matrix1, matrix2]` works for you. It is described in the [documentation on `Correlation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Correlation.html).

Answer (score 9):

Based on the [description you provided](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html) from the MATLAB documentation, `corr2` is computed as

$$\frac{\sum_m \sum_n (A_{mn} - \bar{A}) (B_{mn} - \bar{B})}{\sqrt{\left(\sum_m \sum_n (A_{mn} - \bar{A})^2\right) \left(\sum_m \sum_n (B_{mn} - \bar{B})^2\right)}} $$

Assuming that the [`mean2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mean2.html) function that gives the values of $ \bar{A} $ and $ \bar{B} $ does the obvious thing (i.e., it's equivalent to `Mean @* Flatten` in *Mathematica*), transcribing this formula into *Mathematica* is straightforward (although the result is hardly idiomatic or efficient!)

```
corr2[a_?MatrixQ, b_?MatrixQ] /; Dimensions[a] == Dimensions[b] :=
 With[{
   abar = Mean @ Flatten @ a, bbar = Mean @ Flatten @ b,
   m = First @ Dimensions @ a, n = Last @ Dimensions @ a
   },

  Sum[(a[[i, j]] - abar)*(b[[i, j]] - bbar), {i, m}, {j, n}]/
   Sqrt[
    Sum[(a[[i, j]] - abar)^2, {i, m}, {j, n}]*
     Sum[(b[[i, j]] - bbar)^2, {i, m}, {j, n}]]]
```

Now, since this is *Mathematica*, we can pass symbolic matrices to this function, in addition to numerically valued ones.

```
A = Array[a, {2, 2}];
B = Array[b, {2, 2}];
```

To check how this compares to the results from *Mathematica*'s [`Correlation` function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Correlation.html), I just tried doing things directly:

```
In[3]:= Simplify[corr2[A, B] == Correlation[A, B]]
Out[3]= (* a big old mess omitted *)
```

I noticed a couple things in the output for `Correlation[A, B]`. One is that it returned a vector when passed two matrices, which is evidently not what we want, so we'll have to try something else. The other is that it assumes that `A` and `B` can be complex and does complex conjugation on `B`, which doesn't seem to be part of `corr2`'s specification. The first can be solved by treating `A` and `B` as just their lists of elements (using `Flatten`), and the second can be addressed by telling `Simplify` to assume that the elements of `A` and `B` are real-valued:

```
In[4]:= Simplify[corr2[A, B] == Correlation[A, B], 
         Assumptions -> {a[__], b[__]} ∈ Reals]
Out[4]= True
```

Thus, provided you're dealing with real-valued matrices, the following is likely to be a good implementation of `corr2`:

```
corr2[a_?MatrixQ, b_?MatrixQ] /; Dimensions[a] == Dimensions[b] :=
 Correlation[Flatten @ a, Flatten @ b]
```

Comment: A slightly more idiomatic translation of the formula: `With[{ma = Mean[Flatten[a]], mb = Mean[Flatten[b]]}, Total[(a - ma) (b - mb), 2]/Sqrt[Total[(a - ma)^2, 2] Total[(b - mb)^2, 2]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, that's better, but I wanted to make the equivalence to the MATLAB docs' description as obvious as possible.

Comment: Oh, of course; I just wrote it out for reference. :)

Comment: I finally looked through `corr2.m`; as expected of MATLAB code, it's using a Hadamard product and `sum()`; that is, almost exactly like the snippet in my first comment.